# MySQL database shifted right

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL database running on my mac. After an edit in the UmbrellaQR column, the entire database shifted right. It should look lined up and I am not sure how to solve this. Any solution appreciated! Thank you~

[image: Database problem?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you! I agree that it is a displaying error. What I did was that I restarted MySQL again and it looked the same as before again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this looks more like a displaying problem in your shell.

try to pipe the output to a file and see if the problem still exists.